# Find consecutive indices of common values in a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, group-by

For the `DataFrame` below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Tesla','Tesla','Tesla','Toyota','Ford','Ford','Ford','BMW','BMW','BMW','Mercedes','Mercedes','Mercedes'],
                   'Type': ['Model X','Model X','Model X','Corolla','Bronco','Bronco','Mustang','3 Series','-','-','Alpha','Alpha','S-Class'],
                   'Year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020, 2015, 2015, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2020],
                   'Price': [85000, 90000, 95000, 20000, 35000, 35000, 45000, 40000, 40000, 65000, 50000, 50000, 75000],
                   'Color': ['White','White','White','Red','Blue','Blue','Yellow','Silver','Silver','Black','White','White','Black']
                  })
```

`df`

```
    Name    Type     Year   Price   Color
0   Tesla   Model X  2015   85000   White
1   Tesla   Model X  2015   90000   White
2   Tesla   Model X  2015   95000   White
3   Toyota  Corolla  2017   20000   Red
4   Ford    Bronco   2018   35000   Blue
5   Ford    Bronco   2018   35000   Blue
6   Ford    Mustang  2020   45000   Yellow
7   BMW     3 Series 2015   40000   Silver
8   BMW  -   2015   40000   Silver
9   BMW  -   2017   65000   Black
10  Mercedes Alpha   2018   50000   White
11  Mercedes Alpha   2018   50000   White
12  Mercedes S-Class 2020   75000   Black
```

For each `Name` column groups, I am trying to find the corresponding `start index` and `end index` of consecutive common values in other columns. if the value repeat consecutively it should be considered as common and store it to a dictionary with key as start index and value as end index.

For example `Tesla` has `Model X` common in the `Type` column, so in the `Type` column I should get the `start index` of `Model X` and `end index` of `Model X`  as the first value in a dictionary with `start index` : `end index as the key value pair of the dictionary.

Similarly, for the `Color` column `Blue` should have `start index` as 4 and `end index` as 5 and for the `Year` column `2015` should have `start index` as 0 and `end index` as 2.

Expected Output:

`Name` :

```
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 6, 7: 9, 10: 12}
```

`Type` :

```
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12}
```

`Year` :

```
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12] }
```

`Price`:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12}
```

`Color`:

```
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 9, 10: 11, 12:12}
```

What I tried

```
def find_indices(df, column):
    df1 = df.index.to_series().groupby(df[column]).agg(['first', 'last']).reset_index()
    df1 = df1.sort_values("first").reset_index()
    first_last_rows = df1.set_index('first')['last'].to_dict()
    print(column + ":")
    print(first_last_rows)
```

Output I got

```
Name:
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 6, 7: 9, 10: 12}
Type:
{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12}
Year:
{0: 8, 3: 9, 4: 11, 6: 12}
Price:
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12}
Color:
{0: 11, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 12}
```

In the output I got `Year` and `Color` columns end values are from disjoint group so it is not finding the consecutive common values(or the values are for different `Name`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a group of consecutive values. For that a well known method is to use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and then groupby, and then for your problem you take first index and last index of each group and then build a dict as below:

```
col = "Year"
col_dict = dict(
    df.groupby(df[col].ne(df[col].shift()).cumsum())[col]
    .agg(lambda x: (x.index[0], x.index[-1]))
    .values
)
print(col_dict)

{0: 2, 3: 3, 4: 5, 6: 6, 7: 8, 9: 9, 10: 11, 12: 12}
```